# Easytether .deb won't install due to errors

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 12.4 64amd. I cant get easy tether to install regardless of which version I use (32 or 64bit) but I keep getting an error when I try to run it in the command line.

It tells me it not a valid deb file. If I click it on the desktop the install manager comes up but the install button is not highlighted for me to click to install it that way.

When I run `sudo dpkg -i easytether_0.7.3-1_i386.deb` on the package the output is:

> dpkg-deb: error: `easytether_0.7.3-1_i386.deb' is not a debian format archive dpkg: error processing easytether_0.7.3-1_i386.deb (--install): subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: easytether_0.7.3-1_i386.deb

Please help. I'll be using my phone as internet modem.

Comment: What phone do you have? Most Android phones don't need additional software to use USB tethering.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal ( by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut ) and type `easytether connect` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then minimize the terminal - if you close it it will end. No `sudo` and you don't really need to install the `deb` package as long as its there to be accessed.

Hope this helps.